# Deploying Custom SSIS 2012 Component

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis

I am trying to deploy a basic custom component, following the documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms136078.aspx)

My code for the custom component is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline;

namespace MattsCustomComponent
{
    [DtsPipelineComponent (DisplayName = "Matts Custom Component", ComponentType =    ComponentType.Transform)]
    public class MattsCustomComponent : PipelineComponent
    {
        public override void ProcessInput(int inputID, PipelineBuffer buffer)
        {
            int numberOfRows = buffer.RowCount;
            bool eof = buffer.EndOfRowset;
        }

    }
}
```

As you can see it is very basic. But when I deploy the dll to the GAC and to `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\PipelineComponents`

It doesn't appear in the SSIS toolbar, am I missing something in adding custom components? the guides online all seem to say that you just need to copy the dll to the gac and the relevant folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue that I had here was that after further investigation we have discovered that to use visual studio 2012, you need to have SQL Server 2012 installed when working with ssis projects.

If a custom component has been built with sql server 2008 assemblies, the component will only be available to use in visual studio 2008.

If a custom component has been built with sql server 2012 assemblies, the component will only be available to use in visual studio 2012.

For now the only solution is to install visual studio 2008 and migrate the project to Visual Studio 2012 once we have also migrated to SQL Server 2012.

Answer (score 0):

Use `gacutil /i YourComponentPath`, in command prompt in order to install your custom component.

You can use following reference in order to install your component:

[Installing Custom SSIS Components into GAC Using PowerShell](http://www.pawlowski.cz/2012/04/installing-custom-ssis-components-gac-powershell/)

Comment: That't what I am using to install it, but still not appearing. I can see it has been added to the GAC successfully

Answer (score 0):

This was happening to me, as well. I had installed the .dll to the GAC, but the component would not appear in the SSIS Toolbox in Visual Studio (SSDT).

What worked for me was to install the .dll under the 32-bit folder structure for SQL Server.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\PipelineComponents
```

I suspect this is due to the fact that SSDT is also 32-bit.